# Equivalent of controller in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, controller

I'm trying to update existing angular 1 application to angular 2. I'm confused, there is nothing about controllers. What is the easiest way to migrate controllers to Angular 2?

Comment: For what purpose. Don't expect stuff to be translatable 1:1. Angular2 is entirely different from Angular1. Is this about ES5/6 or TypeScript?

Comment: I'm moving to TS side

Comment: I don't know Angular1 well but I guess you just create a component, directive or service class depending on what you try to accomplish.

Comment: As pointed in previous comments, angular2 doesn't works like angularjs (or angular1) there is no controller in this version, but I think you can implement an equivalent app just using components. Do you have any example of code you want to implement in angular2?

Comment: The controller is the component .ts file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular2 is built from the ground up. Your best solution is to use Angular2 "Components".

Read more about Components at https://angular.io/api/core/Component

Comment: Link in the answer is dead.

Comment: @AndrewPalmer, the link works for me